# Discord.py não tô conseguindo implementar o ''Else'' no meu comando

Tags: python, syntax-error, comandos, discord.py

Bom, eu estou tentando criar um comando de "avatar", porém só mostra o icon, e eu queria fazer que meu comando mostrasse gif também. Só que eu queria implementar o "else" no comando, mas fica dando erro de "Syntax", se alguém puder ajudar a ajeitar o meu código, etc

Meu código:

```
@commands.command()
    async def avatar(self, ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
        if user == None:
            user = ctx.author
        icon_url2 = user.avatar_url_as
        icon_url = user.avatar_url

        avatarEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f'{user.name}\nClique no icon para baixá-lo.', timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),color=discord.Color.dark_blue())
        avatarEmbed.set_image(url=f'{icon_url}')

        await ctx.send(embed=avatarEmbed)
```

Se eu coloco "Else" abaixo do await, aparece isso:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax (talks.py, line 346)

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer fazer o seguinte:

```
@commands.command()
async def avatar(self, ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author
    icon_url2 = user.avatar_url_as
    icon_url = user.avatar_url

    avatarEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f'{user.name}\nClique no icon para baixá-lo.', timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),color=discord.Color.dark_blue())
    avatarEmbed.set_image(url=f'{icon_url}')

    await ctx.send(embed=avatarEmbed)
    else:
        #seu codigo aqui
```

Porem em estruturas condicionais o else deve estar diretamente após o if, exemplo:

```
@commands.command()
async def avatar(self, ctx, user: discord.Member=None):
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author
    else:
        #seu codigo aqui
    icon_url2 = user.avatar_url_as
    icon_url = user.avatar_url

    avatarEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f'{user.name}\nClique no icon para baixá-lo.', timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),color=discord.Color.dark_blue())
    avatarEmbed.set_image(url=f'{icon_url}')

    await ctx.send(embed=avatarEmbed)
```

Isso deve funcionar, qualquer duvida só perguntar.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, ajudou muito.

Answer (score -1):

Não necessita-se colocar um `else:`nesse código, já usei no meu Bot sem o `else:` em comandos de ship, userinfo e perfil e deu certo